# Why isn't Tensorflow/Keras Flatten layer flattening my array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the `tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten` layer outside of a model to flatten a 4x4 tensor. I can't figure out why the `Flatten` layer isn't actually flattening my array.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

flayer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
X = tf.constant(np.random.random((4,4)),dtype=tf.float32)
Xf = flatten_layer(X)
print(Xf)
```

and `print(Xf)` shows

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.9866459  0.52488756 0.86211777 0.06254051]
 [0.32552275 0.23201537 0.8646714  0.80754006]
 [0.55823076 0.51929855 0.538077   0.4111973 ]
 [0.95845264 0.14468837 0.30223057 0.09648433]], shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32)
```

Why doesn't my flatten layer output a 16x1 tensor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the `Flatten()` layer assumes that the first dimension is the number of samples, so it returns 4 flattened rows. You have 4 observations, and 1D input for each of these already. It would behave differently if you had data with shape `(32, 28, 28, 1)`, for example, which has a higher dimensionality for each row.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

flayer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
X = tf.constant(np.random.random((32, 28, 28, 1)),dtype=tf.float32)
Xf = flayer(X)
print(Xf.shape)
```

```
(32, 784)
```

If you meant to flatten one observation with shape `(4, 4)`, you should add a batch dimension for it to work:

```
X = tf.constant(np.random.random((1, 4, 4)),dtype=tf.float32)
Xf = flayer(X)
print(Xf.shape)
```

```
(1, 16)
```